# Using flex 4 sdk in flex builder 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder, flash-builder

This question may be an absolute crap. Can i use the flex 4 sdk in flex builder 3? i have a licensed version of flex builder 3 professional. so if i need to use flex 4 sdk in it, do i need to buy flash builder? cant i get all the new components in flex builder 3?

Regards,
PK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it in Flex Builder. Just download it from [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4). And configure it in Project->Properties->Flex Compiler - there's a button "Configure Flex SDKs...".

Comment: will i see the flex 4 components int he component tool bar then??? i did like that, but am not seeing that

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to set the required flash version to 10.0.0 or you will get the following:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Matrix3D.
```

Comment: that is great.. i was wondering how to solve that... awesome :) i am sorry i can upvote it only once :(